# Conditional Output on cell based on 2 different "IF(REGEXMATCH" functions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

First of all sorry if I am not clear. it is my first question. 
I am trying to make a cell give an output with `IF(REGEXMATCH` on the cell A1 for example

```
=IF(RegExMatch(A2,"YES"),"Good"
```

I also need the same cell to give another output based on another cell

```
=IF(RegExMatch(A3,"NO"),"OK"
```

Important to say, both terms will never give TRUE at the same time, so basically give the output of the argument that returns a TRUE case.
my bottom question is how to combine both terms and make only the one that is TRUE to return an output without being dependent on the other term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "YES"), "Good",
              IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "NO"),  "OK", )))
```

[image: 0]